# How to return a random sentence in Twitch chat, using Streamer.bot?

Tags: c#

This is a simple functionality I have in my chatbot, but I want to customize it a little bit.
Right now, when a user types !lurk, it returns one message.
I want to add multiple other messages, and for it to pick a random one each time a user uses the command.

I would also like to have a separate list of sentences for when they come BACK from lurking. If you notice in the code, there's a second set where it displays a different message when the user uses the command a second time. It would also be nice if I could get it to un-lurk the user whenever they type ANYTHING in chat, instead of them having to use the command again.

Here's the code from inside the bot:

````
using System;

public class CPHInline
{
    public bool Execute()
    {
        int connectionID = 0;
        
        int count;
        int totalCount;
        string messageOut;
        string userName = args["user"].ToString();
        bool lurker = CPH.GetUserVar<bool>(userName, "lurker", true);
        count = CPH.GetGlobalVar<int>("lurkCount", true);
        totalCount = CPH.GetGlobalVar<int>("totalLurkCount", true);
        string inString = args["rawInput"].ToString();
        string[] outputer = inString.Split(' ');

        if(String.Equals(outputer[0].ToLower(), "")) {
            if(lurker == true) {
                count--;
                CPH.SetUserVar(userName, "lurker", false, true);
                messageOut = $"{userName} is no longer lurking! Current Lurkers are now: {count}.";
            } else if(lurker == false) {
                count++;
                totalCount++;
                CPH.SetUserVar(userName, "lurker", true, true);
                messageOut = $"{userName} is now lurking! Current Lurkers are now: {count}. We're now at {totalCount} all time lurkers!";
            } else {
                messageOut = "No Bueno";
            }
        } else if(String.Equals(outputer[0].ToLower(), "check")) {
            if(lurker) {
                messageOut = $"You are currently lurking! The current amount of lurkers: {count}. Total Lurkers: {totalCount}";
            } else if(!lurker) {
                messageOut = $"The current amount of lurkers: {count}. Total Lurkers: {totalCount}"; 
            } else {
                messageOut = "No Bueno";
            }
        } else if(String.Equals(outputer[0].ToLower(), "reset")) {
            count = 0;
            messageOut = $"The total amount of lurkers have been reset. New Count: {count}"; 
        } else {
            messageOut = "Incorrect usuage of the !lurk command";
        }

        CPH.SendMessage(messageOut);
        CPH.SetGlobalVar("totalLurkCount", totalCount, true);
        CPH.SetGlobalVar("lurkCount", count, true);
        return true;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have only added an example with the lurk part. You can apply the same thing for the unlurk part:

```
using System;

public class CPHInline
{
    public bool Execute()
    {
        int connectionID = 0;
        
        int count;
        int totalCount;
        string messageOut;
        string userName = args["user"].ToString();
        bool lurker = CPH.GetUserVar<bool>(userName, "lurker", true);
        count = CPH.GetGlobalVar<int>("lurkCount", true);
        totalCount = CPH.GetGlobalVar<int>("totalLurkCount", true);
        string inString = args["rawInput"].ToString();
        string[] outputer = inString.Split(' ');

        if(String.Equals(outputer[0].ToLower(), "")) {
            if(lurker == true) {
                count--;
                CPH.SetUserVar(userName, "lurker", false, true);
                messageOut = $"{userName} is no longer lurking! Current Lurkers are now: {count}.";
            } else if(lurker == false) {
                count++;
                totalCount++;
                CPH.SetUserVar(userName, "lurker", true, true);
                messageOut = fetchLurkMsg(userName, count, totalCount); // Swapped for the new method
            } else {
                messageOut = "No Bueno";
            }
        } else if(String.Equals(outputer[0].ToLower(), "check")) {
            if(lurker) {
                messageOut = $"You are currently lurking! The current amount of lurkers: {count}. Total Lurkers: {totalCount}";
            } else if(!lurker) {
                messageOut = $"The current amount of lurkers: {count}. Total Lurkers: {totalCount}"; 
            } else {
                messageOut = "No Bueno";
            }
        } else if(String.Equals(outputer[0].ToLower(), "reset")) {
            count = 0;
            messageOut = $"The total amount of lurkers have been reset. New Count: {count}"; 
        } else {
            messageOut = "Incorrect usuage of the !lurk command";
        }

        CPH.SendMessage(messageOut);
        CPH.SetGlobalVar("totalLurkCount", totalCount, true);
        CPH.SetGlobalVar("lurkCount", count, true);
        return true;
    }

    private string fetchLurkMsg(string userName, int count, int totalCount) {
        // Example messages to pick from
        string[] lurkMsgs = new string[] {
            $"{userName} is now lurking! Current Lurkers are now: {count}. We're now at {totalCount} all time lurkers!",
            $"{userName} is now lurking in the shadows! Current Lurkers are now: {count}. We're now at {totalCount} all time lurkers!",
            $"{userName} has gone to the abyss! Current Lurkers are now: {count}. We're now at {totalCount} all time lurkers!",
            $"I see {userName}? I see {userName} not? Current Lurkers are now: {count}. We're now at {totalCount} all time lurkers!"
        };

        // Generate a random number, used to pick a random message. We currently
        // have 4 messages, so we pick any random number between 0 and 4
        return lurkMsgs[new Random().Next(0, 4)];
    }
}
```

There's a bit of logic iffyness with the !lurk reset (if someone goes to lurk, then the lurk is reset, and then the person unlurks, the count goes in to the negative, but that's another issue where you'll have to handle cases like that more carefully)

Also I think the part where you want to auto-unlurk anyone speaking is another question. I think you'll essentially have to create a regex command with a single dot (to match anything) and then create an action to check if the user is has the lurker variable set to true and handle it in that action. Should be easier to implement than your current code IMO.